# Zip files in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, zip, unzip

I have a file in the directory "./Data/Engine/modules/xnc.zip" that I want to unzip to "./Data/Engine/modules/xnc".

After that, I will write to the files and I need to rezip it easily!

I would create my own method but I am not capable of creating a full zip archive zip and unzip the module

Does anyone have any ideas?

Edit: Thanks for all the help!
Sadly I can't send questions anymore though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nodejs module [AdmZip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) to for zipping and unzipping of files.

**Installation:**

```
npm install adm-zip
```

**Code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const AdmZip = require('adm-zip');


  var zip = new AdmZip(".sample.zip");
  zip.extractEntryTo(/*entry name*/"sample.txt", /*target path*/"D:/stackoverflow", /*maintainEntryPath*/false, /*overwrite*/true);
  fs.appendFileSync('sample.txt', 'data to append');
  zip.addLocalFile('D:/stackoverflow/sample.txt')
  zip.writeZip('D:/stackoverflow/sample.zip')
```

if you want to remove the unzipped file

```
fs.unlinkSync('sample.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [adm-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adm-zip) to zip/unzip files easily

Answer (score 0):

You could use zip/unzip in a child process:

```
const cp = require('child_process')

exec('unzip path/to/zip_file.zip', (err) => {
  if(err) return console.log(err)
  /// Files have been unzipped
})
```